# pyspark - can PYTHONPATH be used for the Python interpreter on worker nodes to find Python modules?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Please advise where I should look into to understand the in-detail mechanism on how PySpark finds Python modules on the worker nodes, especially the usage of `PHTHONPATH`.

[image]

### PYTHONPATH variable

[Environment Variables](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#environment-variables) says environment variables defined in spark-env.sh could be used.

> Certain Spark settings can be configured through environment variables, which are read from the conf/spark-env.sh script in the directory where Spark is installed

Then if I define `PHTHONPATH` in spark-env.sh on all the worker nodes, will PySpark start a Python interpreter process with the `PYTHONPATH` being passed to the UNIX process, and Python modules will be loaded from the `PYTHONPATH`?

### Precedence of PYTHONPATH when --archives is used

In case `PHTHONPATH` in spark-env.sh can be used, then what will happen when `--archives` specifies the virtual environment package?

[Python Package Management](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/user_guide/python_packaging.html) says a conda environment can be packaged into a tar.gz and passed to the worker nodes.

> There are multiple ways to manage Python dependencies in the cluster:
>
> - Using PySpark Native Features
> - Using Conda
> - Using Virtualenv
> - Using PEX
>
> Using Conda
>
> ```
> conda create -y -n pyspark_conda_env -c conda-forge pyarrow pandas conda-pack
> conda activate pyspark_conda_env
> conda pack -f -o pyspark_conda_env.tar.gz
> ```
>
> After that, you can ship it together with scripts or in the code by using the --archives option or spark.archives configuration (spark.yarn.dist.archives in YARN). It automatically unpacks the archive on executors.
>
> ```
> export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=python # Do not set in cluster modes.
> export PYSPARK_PYTHON=./environment/bin/python
> spark-submit --archives pyspark_conda_env.tar.gz#environment app.py
> ```

However when `PYTHONPATH` is defined in spark-env.sh, will `PYTHONPATH` be used and which will take precedence either inside the conda environment or PYTHONPATH?